# puppeteer,estoy tratando de escribir en un input de texto pero no me funciona el id: “ '#form:run' is not a valid selector.”

Tags: nodejs, typescript, scraping, puppeteer

```
(async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(chromeOptions);

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://portal.sidiv.registrocivil.cl/usuarios-portal/pages/DocumentRequestStatus.xhtml', {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
    });

    // await page.type('input[id=form:run]', '245-6');
    // await page.waitFor('*[id=form:run]');
    // await page.$eval('*[id=form:run]', el => el.value = 'admin');
    const inputs = await page.$('#form:run');
    await inputs.type('123');

    //     await page.evaluate(() => {
    //       const rutInput = document.getElementById('form:run');
    //       rutInput.value = '123123';
    //    });
    //    console.log(rutInput)
})()
```

Este es mi código, intenté todas la soluciones que están comentadas en el código y el error que me tira la consola es este:

> (node:10092) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#form:run' is not a valid selector. at puppeteer_evaluation_script:1:33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El id incluye un dos puntos ( `:` ) y eso lo hace un selector no válido para el queryselect ( busca un [pseudoelemento o pseudoclase](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectores_CSS/Pseudo-clases_y_pseudo-elementos) ).

Probá escapeando con `\\` onda: `document.querySelectorAll('*[id=form\\:run]')`

```js
// sin error
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('*[id=form\\:run]'))
console.log(document.querySelector('*[id=form\\:run]').value)

// con error
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('*[id=form:run]'))
console.log(document.querySelector('*[id=form:run]').value)
```

```html
<input id="form:run" value="asdf" />
```

Comment: grande!, me funciono muchisimas gracias.